# MySQL Average of some rows with special weights

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| id |  Column1 |  Column2 |  Column3 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 1  |  1       |  2014    |  0.2     | 
| 2  |  1       |  2013    |  0.5     | 
| 3  |  2       |  2014    |  1.9     | 
| 4  |  2       |  2013    |  1.4     | 
| 5  |  2       |  2012    |  1       | 
| 6  |  2       |  2011    |  0.4     | 
| 7  |  3       |  2016    |  1.4     | 
| 8  |  3       |  2015    |  1.2     | 
| 9  |  3       |  2014    |  0.7     | 
| 10 |  4       |  2015    |  0.5     | 
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

What I'd need is the following
I'd like to average the rows which have the same Column1 value but in a way that the latest data should be multiplied by 0.6 and the rest by 0.3

So for example
where `Column1 = 1, it should output the value of 0.2*0.6+0.5*0.3
      Column1 = 2, 1.9*0.6+((1.4+1+0.4)/3)*0.3
      Column1 = 3, 1.4*0.6+((1.2+0.7)/2)*0.3
      Column1 = 4, 0.5`

Edit: If that's too complex for one query, I'm happy with doing that with more too.

Comment: Does jpql have row_number or other window functions?

Comment: The table has row numbers. But I'm not sure about the window functions.

Comment: Are you aware that 0.6 + 0.3 is not equal to 1? Therefore if there are rows (11,5,2015,0.5) and (12,5,2014,0.5), weighted average for item 5 will be 0.45 instead of 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out here: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eeb9f3/15)

```
SELECT 
    c1, 
    avg(c3), -- this here is the average per weight
    weight,  -- this is the weight
    avg(c3)*weight as weighted_avg -- product between the two
FROM
(
    SELECT
        table1.*,
        if(no_of_lines is null, 
           0.3,                   -- the default weight for >1 lines
           if(no_of_lines = 1 , 
              1,                  -- the weight if there's only 1 line
              0.6                 -- the weight for the 1st line if there are more
           )
        ) as weight
    FROM
        table1
    Left join
    (
        select min(id) as id, count(id) as no_of_lines ,c1
        from table1
        group by c1
    ) tmp on tmp.id = table1.id
) final
group by c1, weight
order by c1 ASC, weight DESC
```

Will output this:

```
c1 | avg(c3) | weight | weighted_avg
------------------------------------
1  | 0.2     |    0.6 | 0.12
1  | 0.5     |    0.3 | 0.15
2  | 1.9     |    0.6 | 1.14
2  | 0.9333  |    0.3 | 0.279
3  | 1.4     |    0.6 | 0.84
3  | 0.95    |    0.3 | 0.285
4  | 0.5     |      1 | 0.5
```

All you need to do now is:

```
SELECT c1, sum(weighted_avg) FROM `that_select`
GROUP by c1
```

Disclaimer:
1) this can probably be simplified a bit, but that's another story
2) remove the comments - might give you errors

Comment: See an earlier version of the sqlFiddle. The final one is /15. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eeb9f3/10 This version isn't precalculating averages per weight.